# ClamAV states virus databases are up to date but FreshClam log file says otherwise

Tags: arch-linux, clamav

I installed ClamAV. The setup was done some time ago, but I've noticed that, apparently, FreshClam hasn't run since September 22nd:

```
[x80486@uplink:~]$ sudo cat /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
--------------------------------------
ClamAV update process started at Fri Jun 30 15:31:00 2023
daily database available for download (remote version: 26955)
Testing database: '/var/lib/clamav/tmp.9c82164f10/clamav-cc2397910639c7390c4707d791014939.tmp-daily.cvd' ...
Database test passed.
daily.cvd updated (version: 26955, sigs: 2037934, f-level: 90, builder: raynman)
main database available for download (remote version: 62)
Testing database: '/var/lib/clamav/tmp.9c82164f10/clamav-2ebd9ccfd37f99327a8188293f1c3485.tmp-main.cvd' ...
Database test passed.
main.cvd updated (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, f-level: 90, builder: sigmgr)
bytecode database available for download (remote version: 334)
Testing database: '/var/lib/clamav/tmp.9c82164f10/clamav-1c6f9beb685cf5d255c0fc2a11405c58.tmp-bytecode.cvd' ...
Database test passed.
bytecode.cvd updated (version: 334, sigs: 91, f-level: 90, builder: anvilleg)
WARNING: Clamd was NOT notified: Can't connect to clamd through /run/clamav/clamd.ctl: No such file or directory
--------------------------------------
freshclam daemon 1.0.1 (OS: Linux, ARCH: x86_64, CPU: x86_64)
ClamAV update process started at Fri Jun 30 15:38:12 2023
daily.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 26955, sigs: 2037934, f-level: 90, builder: raynman)
main.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, f-level: 90, builder: sigmgr)
bytecode.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 334, sigs: 91, f-level: 90, builder: anvilleg)
--------------------------------------
...
--------------------------------------
Received signal: wake up
ClamAV update process started at Thu Sep 21 13:02:41 2023
daily database available for update (local version: 27037, remote version: 27038)
Testing database: '/var/lib/clamav/tmp.e048a53c2e/clamav-0dad46f97ba861f4cdc80aebfee2b3dc.tmp-daily.cld' ...
Database test passed.
daily.cld updated (version: 27038, sigs: 2041081, f-level: 90, builder: raynman)
main.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, f-level: 90, builder: sigmgr)
bytecode.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 334, sigs: 91, f-level: 90, builder: anvilleg)
Clamd successfully notified about the update.
--------------------------------------
Received signal: wake up
ClamAV update process started at Thu Sep 21 20:15:53 2023
daily.cld database is up-to-date (version: 27038, sigs: 2041081, f-level: 90, builder: raynman)
main.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, f-level: 90, builder: sigmgr)
bytecode.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 334, sigs: 91, f-level: 90, builder: anvilleg)
--------------------------------------
Update process terminated
```

The content of `freshclam.log` and its modification timestamp are aligned:

```
[x80486@uplink:~]$ ll /var/log/clamav/ 
total 248K
-rw-r----- 1 clamav 130K Dec 29 16:50 clamd.log
-rw-r----- 1 clamav 108K Sep 22 05:57 freshclam.log
```

Regardless, I see that ClamAV states its virus databases are up to date (today is Dec 29th, 2023):

```bash
[x80486@uplink:~]$ clamscan --version 
ClamAV 1.2.1/27138/Fri Dec 29 04:39:08 2023
```

I don't fully understand how is that possible

FreshClam service is enabled and running:

```
[x80486@uplink:~]$ systemctl status clamav-freshclam.service 
● clamav-freshclam.service - ClamAV virus database updater
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/clamav-freshclam.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-12-29 16:50:52 EST; 4h 16min ago
       Docs: man:freshclam(1)
             man:freshclam.conf(5)
             https://docs.clamav.net/
   Main PID: 1051 (freshclam)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38104)
     Memory: 6.9M (peak: 14.5M zswap: 714.8K)
        CPU: 10ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/clamav-freshclam.service
             └─1051 /usr/bin/freshclam -d --foreground=true

Dec 29 16:50:57 uplink freshclam[1051]: ERROR: check_for_new_database_version: Failed to find daily database using server https://database.clamav.net.
Dec 29 16:50:57 uplink freshclam[1051]: Trying again in 5 secs...
Dec 29 16:51:02 uplink freshclam[1051]: Trying to retrieve CVD header from https://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd
Dec 29 16:51:02 uplink freshclam[1051]: ERROR: remote_cvdhead: Download failed (6) ERROR:  Message: Couldn't resolve host name
Dec 29 16:51:02 uplink freshclam[1051]: WARNING: Failed to get daily database version information from server: https://database.clamav.net
Dec 29 16:51:02 uplink freshclam[1051]: ERROR: check_for_new_database_version: Failed to find daily database using server https://database.clamav.net.
Dec 29 16:51:02 uplink freshclam[1051]: Giving up on https://database.clamav.net...
Dec 29 16:51:02 uplink freshclam[1051]: ERROR: Update failed for database: daily
Dec 29 16:51:02 uplink freshclam[1051]: ERROR: Database update process failed: HTTP GET failed
Dec 29 16:51:02 uplink freshclam[1051]: ERROR: Update failed.
```

I checked the `systemd` logs (using `journalctl`) for `freshclam` and sometimes those (latest) errors arise, but most of the time the virus databases get updated:

```
[x80486@uplink:~]$ journalctl --since "2023-12-01" --unit clamav-freshclam.service 
Dec 27 10:11:27 uplink freshclam[1097]: ClamAV update process started at Wed Dec 27 10:11:27 2023
Dec 27 10:11:27 uplink freshclam[1097]: daily database available for update (local version: 27135, remote version: 27136)
Dec 27 10:11:28 uplink freshclam[1097]: Testing database: '/var/lib/clamav/tmp.c8cc0017d1/clamav-e36a2a20e61f2ab84e3ae79524c73ae4.tmp-daily.cld' ...
Dec 27 10:11:32 uplink freshclam[1097]: Database test passed.
Dec 27 10:11:32 uplink freshclam[1097]: daily.cld updated (version: 27136, sigs: 2049596, f-level: 90, builder: raynman)
Dec 27 10:11:32 uplink freshclam[1097]: main.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, f-level: 90, builder: sigmgr)
Dec 27 10:11:32 uplink freshclam[1097]: bytecode.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 334, sigs: 91, f-level: 90, builder: anvilleg)
Dec 27 10:11:32 uplink freshclam[1097]: Clamd successfully notified about the update.
Dec 27 16:11:32 uplink freshclam[1097]: Received signal: wake up
Dec 27 16:11:32 uplink freshclam[1097]: ClamAV update process started at Wed Dec 27 16:11:32 2023
Dec 27 16:11:32 uplink freshclam[1097]: daily.cld database is up-to-date (version: 27136, sigs: 2049596, f-level: 90, builder: raynman)
Dec 27 16:11:32 uplink freshclam[1097]: main.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, f-level: 90, builder: sigmgr)
Dec 27 16:11:32 uplink freshclam[1097]: bytecode.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 334, sigs: 91, f-level: 90, builder: anvilleg)
Dec 28 09:27:06 uplink freshclam[1097]: Received signal: wake up
Dec 28 09:27:06 uplink freshclam[1097]: ClamAV update process started at Thu Dec 28 09:27:06 2023
Dec 28 09:27:06 uplink freshclam[1097]: daily database available for update (local version: 27136, remote version: 27137)
Dec 28 09:27:07 uplink freshclam[1097]: Testing database: '/var/lib/clamav/tmp.c8cc0017d1/clamav-f96d7409ae21590143a85f4d2bc16f4c.tmp-daily.cld' ...
Dec 28 09:27:11 uplink freshclam[1097]: Database test passed.
Dec 28 09:27:11 uplink freshclam[1097]: daily.cld updated (version: 27137, sigs: 2049636, f-level: 90, builder: raynman)
Dec 28 09:27:11 uplink freshclam[1097]: main.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, f-level: 90, builder: sigmgr)
Dec 28 09:27:11 uplink freshclam[1097]: bytecode.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 334, sigs: 91, f-level: 90, builder: anvilleg)
Dec 28 09:27:11 uplink freshclam[1097]: Clamd successfully notified about the update.
Dec 28 15:27:11 uplink freshclam[1097]: Received signal: wake up
Dec 28 15:27:11 uplink freshclam[1097]: ClamAV update process started at Thu Dec 28 15:27:11 2023
Dec 28 15:27:11 uplink freshclam[1097]: daily.cld database is up-to-date (version: 27137, sigs: 2049636, f-level: 90, builder: raynman)
Dec 28 15:27:11 uplink freshclam[1097]: main.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, f-level: 90, builder: sigmgr)
Dec 28 15:27:11 uplink freshclam[1097]: bytecode.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 334, sigs: 91, f-level: 90, builder: anvilleg)
Dec 28 21:27:11 uplink freshclam[1097]: Received signal: wake up
Dec 28 21:27:11 uplink freshclam[1097]: ClamAV update process started at Thu Dec 28 21:27:11 2023
Dec 28 21:27:11 uplink freshclam[1097]: daily.cld database is up-to-date (version: 27137, sigs: 2049636, f-level: 90, builder: raynman)
Dec 28 21:27:11 uplink freshclam[1097]: main.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, f-level: 90, builder: sigmgr)
Dec 28 21:27:11 uplink freshclam[1097]: bytecode.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 334, sigs: 91, f-level: 90, builder: anvilleg)
Dec 29 11:11:45 uplink freshclam[1097]: Received signal: wake up
Dec 29 11:11:45 uplink freshclam[1097]: ClamAV update process started at Fri Dec 29 11:11:45 2023
Dec 29 11:11:45 uplink freshclam[1097]: daily database available for update (local version: 27137, remote version: 27138)
Dec 29 11:11:46 uplink freshclam[1097]: Testing database: '/var/lib/clamav/tmp.c8cc0017d1/clamav-136aa724061e4b2bc840a86b67cb13d2.tmp-daily.cld' ...
Dec 29 11:11:50 uplink freshclam[1097]: Database test passed.
Dec 29 11:11:50 uplink freshclam[1097]: daily.cld updated (version: 27138, sigs: 2049785, f-level: 90, builder: raynman)
Dec 29 11:11:50 uplink freshclam[1097]: main.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, f-level: 90, builder: sigmgr)
Dec 29 11:11:50 uplink freshclam[1097]: bytecode.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 334, sigs: 91, f-level: 90, builder: anvilleg)
Dec 29 11:11:50 uplink freshclam[1097]: Clamd successfully notified about the update.
Dec 29 16:50:17 uplink freshclam[1097]: Update process terminated
Dec 29 16:50:18 uplink systemd[1]: clamav-freshclam.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 29 16:50:18 uplink systemd[1]: clamav-freshclam.service: Consumed 1min 10.200s CPU time, 1.3G memory peak.
Dec 29 16:50:52 uplink freshclam[1051]: ClamAV update process started at Fri Dec 29 16:50:52 2023
Dec 29 16:50:52 uplink freshclam[1051]: WARNING: Can't query current.cvd.clamav.net
Dec 29 16:50:52 uplink freshclam[1051]: WARNING: Invalid DNS reply. Falling back to HTTP mode.
Dec 29 16:50:52 uplink freshclam[1051]: Trying to retrieve CVD header from https://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd
Dec 29 16:50:52 uplink freshclam[1051]: WARNING: remote_cvdhead: Download failed (6) WARNING:  Message: Couldn't resolve host name
Dec 29 16:50:52 uplink freshclam[1051]: WARNING: Failed to get daily database version information from server: https://database.clamav.net
Dec 29 16:50:52 uplink freshclam[1051]: ERROR: check_for_new_database_version: Failed to find daily database using server https://database.clamav.net.
Dec 29 16:50:52 uplink freshclam[1051]: Trying again in 5 secs...
Dec 29 16:50:57 uplink freshclam[1051]: Trying to retrieve CVD header from https://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd
Dec 29 16:50:57 uplink freshclam[1051]: WARNING: remote_cvdhead: Download failed (6) WARNING:  Message: Couldn't resolve host name
Dec 29 16:50:57 uplink freshclam[1051]: WARNING: Failed to get daily database version information from server: https://database.clamav.net
Dec 29 16:50:57 uplink freshclam[1051]: ERROR: check_for_new_database_version: Failed to find daily database using server https://database.clamav.net.
Dec 29 16:50:57 uplink freshclam[1051]: Trying again in 5 secs...
Dec 29 16:51:02 uplink freshclam[1051]: Trying to retrieve CVD header from https://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd
Dec 29 16:51:02 uplink freshclam[1051]: ERROR: remote_cvdhead: Download failed (6) ERROR:  Message: Couldn't resolve host name
Dec 29 16:51:02 uplink freshclam[1051]: WARNING: Failed to get daily database version information from server: https://database.clamav.net
Dec 29 16:51:02 uplink freshclam[1051]: ERROR: check_for_new_database_version: Failed to find daily database using server https://database.clamav.net.
Dec 29 16:51:02 uplink freshclam[1051]: Giving up on https://database.clamav.net...
Dec 29 16:51:02 uplink freshclam[1051]: ERROR: Update failed for database: daily
Dec 29 16:51:02 uplink freshclam[1051]: ERROR: Database update process failed: HTTP GET failed
Dec 29 16:51:02 uplink freshclam[1051]: ERROR: Update failed.
```

What I'm trying to understand is why there is no correlation between `freshclam.log` and the actual state of the system. It appears to me the virus databases are indeed up to date based on the `systemd` messages for `freshclam`, but that's not reflected in `freshclam.log`.

Is there a way to fix that...or am I missing something?

---

#### UPDATES

I went ahead and verified the user and group configured for ClamAV, and they own and have the correct privileges. It all makes sense since `/var/log/clamav/clamd.log` is updated accordingly — though `/var/log/clamav/freshclam.log` is not

I stopped `clamav-freshclam.service` and removed `/var/log/clamav/freshclam.log` just to verify if `UpdateLogFile /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log` setting (from `/etc/clamav/freshclam.conf`) was actually doing something, and the process couldn't start because the file didn't exist:

```
Dec 29 22:31:57 uplink freshclam[13277]: ERROR: lchown to user 'clamav' failed on
Dec 29 22:31:57 uplink freshclam[13277]: log file '/var/log/clamav/freshclam.log'.
Dec 29 22:31:57 uplink freshclam[13277]: Error was 'No such file or directory'
Dec 29 22:31:57 uplink freshclam[13277]: WARNING: lchown to user 'clamav' failed on log file '/var/log/clamav/freshclam.log'.  Error was 'No such file or directory'
Dec 29 22:31:57 uplink freshclam[13277]: ERROR: Failed to switch to clamav user.
Dec 29 22:31:57 uplink systemd[1]: clamav-freshclam.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=9/n/a
Dec 29 22:31:57 uplink systemd[1]: clamav-freshclam.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

So I made a backup and created a new `/var/log/clamav/freshclam.log` file the correct privileges and permissions...just to see that `clamav-freshclam.service` started successfully, but not a single log statement in that file

Comment: The timestamp on freshclam.log is 3 months ago.  Are you sure this log file is still in use?  Maybe an update you did in September changed how things log?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to recap because I just run `pacman -Syyu` once or twice a month, and that brings over plenty of updates, but I'm certain I didn't modify any configuration settings for ClamAV. I also see that `UpdateLogFile /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log` (in `/etc/clamav/freshclam.conf`) actually points correctly to the log file, and the privileges and permissions are also correctly set.

Comment: ClamAV is a signature-based scanner used to detect Windows malware in (usually) e-mail files. Why use it on Linux?

Comment: @waltinator that’s its primary use-case (as designed), but it also detects Linux malware and can be used to scan downloads etc.

Comment: @waltinator this is the second ClamAV post I've seen you incorrectly state this, please read about the product.